# RSS Feed wont show using Feedwind

Tags: xml, rss, feed

Hello all (first post in here)

**Problem:**
My rss feed won't load properly using the [Feed mikle rss widget](https://feed.mikle.com/) more precisely it won't show up on my webpage.

**What i have tried:**
I have tried using  [w3 rss feed validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/) and is validate just fine, i have tried looking around their site and cant seem to see what is wrong, is the enclouse to large?

**Url:** lamp2.sdu.dk/~pewen16/chokoladefabrikken/Chokoladefabrikkenrss.xml to the feed

**NB:** here is my code doing it for a school project

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>Chokoladefabrikkens Blog</title>
  <link>http://lamp2.sdu.dk/~pewen16/chokoladefabrikken/kageBlog.html</link>
  <description>Masser af inspirerende opskrifter på chokoladekager</description>
  <item>
    <title>Ny årstid, nye ingredienser</title>
    <link>http://lamp2.sdu.dk/~pewen16/chokoladefabrikken/kageNews1.html</link>
    <description>Vi byder efteråret velkommen med helt nye opskrifter som er inspireret af årstiden, vi snakker om alt fra enebær, tranebær til det halloween inspireret køkken med græskar som ingredienser for vores nye efterårs kollektion af fremragende chokoladekager</description>
    <enclosure url="http://lamp2.sdu.dk/~pewen16/chokoladefabrikken/soundfiles/nyhed1.mp3"
    length="864256" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Julehygge</title>
    <link>http://lamp2.sdu.dk/~pewen16/chokoladefabrikken/kageNews2.html</link>
    <description>Julen nærmer sig i hastige skridt, så skal julebageriet i gang igen i år og her på chokoladefabrikken er vi spændte på at fremvise alle de nye opskrifter vi har planer om at dele med jer!</description>
    <enclosure url="http://lamp2.sdu.dk/~pewen16/chokoladefabrikken/soundfiles/nyhed1.mp3"
    length="335431" type="audio/mpeg" />
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Mette Blomsterberg udgået pga. doping</title>
    <link>http://lamp2.sdu.dk/~pewen16/chokoladefabrikken/kageNews3.html</link>
    <description>Mette Blomsterberg er desværre udgået af den store bagedyst på grund af doping og andet snask. Havde man den overbevisning af at forvente hasselnødder og andet godt i hendes kager skal man tro om igen.. </description>
    <enclosure url="http://lamp2.sdu.dk/~pewen16/chokoladefabrikken/soundfiles/nyhed3.mp3"
    length="713553" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Can you add the URL of the feed you're trying to use with this widget? Maybe, check the console "F12" in the (Network) tab and reload the page, and see if the request is interrupted or something similar is happening..Can you add also if the widget shows any message/error?

Comment: hey and thanks for the comment, i have updated the post with the link to the feed, for the error message is show _Unknown error. (Couldn't resolve host 'www.adeneng-faculty.edu.ye')_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tested the URL in the widget, the first time it says:

> Unknown error. (Parse failed)

But after reload the page and enter again the sample URL that you added to your question, it worked.

Maybe it's something with the widget, because I made a few more tests with the default url provided in the widget and with your sample URL and the same error ocurred.

[This is the widget with your URL sample](https://feed.mikle.com/widget/v2/?widget_parameter=%7B%22sources%22%3A%5B%7B%22source%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flamp2.sdu.dk%2F~pewen16%2Fchokoladefabrikken%2FChokoladefabrikkenrss.xml%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22RSS%22%7D%5D%2C%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22width%22%3A0%2C%22height%22%3A%22400%22%2C%22height_by_article%22%3A0%2C%22target%22%3A%22_blank%22%2C%22font%22%3A%22Arial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20sans-serif%22%2C%22title_font_size%22%3A%2216%22%2C%22item_title_font_size%22%3A%2216%22%2C%22item_description_font_size%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22border%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22css_url%22%3A%22%22%2C%22responsive%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22text_direction%22%3A%22left%22%2C%22text_alignment%22%3A%22left%22%2C%22corner%22%3A%22rounded%22%2C%22scroll%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22auto_scroll%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22auto_scroll_direction%22%3A%22up%22%2C%22auto_scroll_step_speed%22%3A%224%22%2C%22auto_scroll_mc_speed%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%22new%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22title_sentence%22%3A%22%22%2C%22title_link%22%3A%22%22%2C%22title_bgcolor%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22title_color%22%3A%22%23505659%22%2C%22title_bgimage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22item_bgcolor%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22item_bgimage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22item_title_length%22%3A%2255%22%2C%22item_title_color%22%3A%22%232e7ec8%22%2C%22item_border_bottom%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22item_description%22%3A%22both%22%2C%22item_link%22%3A%22off%22%2C%22item_description_length%22%3A%22100%22%2C%22item_description_color%22%3A%22%23505659%22%2C%22item_date%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22item_date_format%22%3A%22%25b%20%25e%2C%20%25Y%20%25k%3A%25M%22%2C%22item_date_timezone%22%3A%22%22%2C%22item_description_style%22%3A%22thumbnail%22%2C%22item_thumbnail%22%3A%22crop%22%2C%22item_thumbnail_selection%22%3A%22auto%22%2C%22article_num%22%3A%2215%22%2C%22item_player%22%3A%22youtube%22%2C%22keyword_inc%22%3A%22%22%2C%22keyword_exc%22%3A%22%22%7D).